# Differences between 2 kinds of structure declare

Tags: c, structure, typedef

For this code:

```
typedef struct book_s{
char name[50];
char author[50];
int price;
} book_t;
```

I'm going to declare 2 variables of this structure:

```
struct book_s first_book;
book_t second_book;
```

Are  `first_book` and `second_book` the same type?
If so, are these 2 lines

```
first_book.name

second_book.name
```

are going to give the same type of string for output?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The type-name `book_t` is an *alias* for `struct book_s`. They're identical types, and can be used interchangeably. Therefore the structure *objects* (structure instances) are of identical type as well.

The structure objects (instances) are different and distinct, but they have the same type.

Answer (score 1):

No although they share a type they are completely different variables with a different memory location.

Comment: OP didn't ask if they are the same variable! The question was "are they the same type?"

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm just asking to see if they are the same type, I'm aware that they are 2 different variables and do not share the same values or memory locations

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are both a "book_s" structure **type**
BUT! they are not the same instance/object.

e.g.:

struct book_s first_book; 
// ^- you now have an object called "first_book" of the type book_s
book_t second_book; 
// ^ you now have a second object called "second_book" of the type book_t 
//   which is the alias for struct book_s

setting a string to: first_book.name
will not affect the string in: second_book.name

calling: first_book.name
will return a string but not the same string as the other object "second_book.name"

they both return the same type: string
they both have other values.

hope this helps!

Comment: I'm just asking if they were the same type. Anyway thanks for answering!

Answer (score 1):

These two object declarations

```
struct book_s first_book;
book_t second_book;
```

are equivalent.

In the first declaration there is used the type specifier `struct book_s`. In the second declaration there is used the typedef name that is an alias for the type specifier `struct book_s`.

Moreover you could write the typedef even the following way

```
typedef struct book_s{
    char name[50];
    char author[50];
    int price;
} book_s;
```

And define the objects like

```
struct book_s first_book;
book_s second_book;
```

These expressions

```
first_book.name

second_book.name
```

are member access expressions to the data member `name` of the declared structure of the two objects `first_book` and `second_book`.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct book_s{
    char name[50];
    char author[50];
    int price;
} book_t;

int main(void) 
{
    struct book_s first_book = 
    { 
        "Expert C Programming", "Peter van der Linden", 10
    };
    book_t second_book =
    {
        "Head First C", "David Griffiths and Dawn Griffiths", 15
    };

    printf( "%s by %s (%d)\n", first_book.name, 
                               first_book.author, 
                               first_book.price );
    printf( "%s by %s (%d)\n", second_book.name, 
                               second_book.author, 
                               second_book.price );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
Expert C Programming by Peter van der Linden (10)
Head First C by David Griffiths and Dawn Griffiths (15)
```